Have King Shark and Killer Croc fought before?
In the DC anime Suicide Squad Isekai (2024), I was fascinated by the recurring showdowns between two of DC's aquatic supervillains: King Shark and Killer Croc. Their fights piqued my interest, given their shared "man-aquatic animal" monster motif.
I've tried searching online, but most results focus on hypothetical matchups rather than actual encounters. This got me wondering: has there been a fight before between King Shark and Killer Croc in the comics or other DC media? Or is Suicide Squad Isekai the first time we've seen these two square off?
If they have clashed before, which character came out on top, and how did the fight play out?

Please, "King" Shark was my father. Call me Gerald.

King Shark and Killer Croc fought in the "Sink Atlantis!" storyline in 2018. The fight began in Suicide Squad Vol. 5 #46 and ended in Aquaman Vol. 8 #40, with three pages of it being shown on-panel. Shark won, but Croc didn't really want the fight, and Shark noted afterward that Croc's heart wasn't in it.


Suicide Squad Vol. 5 #46 (November, 2018)




Aquaman Vol. 8 #40 (November, 2018)

